# Написание текстового редактора, отправляющего текст на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Нужно написать web текстовый редактор, который будет отсылать данные из текстовых форм на сервер. Насколько я понял, сделать это можно было посредством XMLHttpRequest (каждая форма отправляется по отдельности, страница не перезагружается). Теоретический код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<tr><td>Text1</td><td>Text2</td><td><textarea>Text3</textarea><button onclick = "send_data()" id="button">Отправить</button></tr>
<script>
    function send_data() {
        button.innerHTML = ' ... ';
        s = button.previousElementSibling;
        var text = s.value;

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "get_data.php";
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(text);

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как тут сделать, чтобы функция send_data опознавала кнопку, которая была нажата (чтобы получать нужный текст) (id только 1) и как писать php файл, который будет принимать информацию и записывать её в файл?

Comment: `send_data(this)`

Comment: Можно подробней? У меня подчёркивает красным, но, увы, быстрее от этого не работает.

Comment: быстрее и не должно работать, должно просто работать. Так как ты хотел кнопку которая была нажата, ты ее так получил

Comment: Это надо было добавлять в onclick. Теперь без красного, но при нажатии ничего не происходит. Подскажи, пожалуйста, на что button менять. js я плохо знаю. на this.button заменил, вроде не работает.

Comment: Ага, разобрался. this в onclick, в function send_data(obj), вызвавший элемент - obj

Comment: Если разобрался добавь свой собственный ответ с описанием решения

Comment: Если разобрались, то добавьте свой собственный ответ с описанием решения.

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на этот элемент вызывается send_data, куда передаётся сам этот элемент, с которым можно выполнять какие-то действия

```
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" onclick="send_data(this)">Send</span>

function send_data(button) {
    button.innerHTML = ' ... ';
}
```